# Postgres trigger not working

Tags: postgresql, database-partitioning, database-trigger

I'm using Postgres version 9.6

I have the items_prt table and I want to add partitions handling on the field:

```
updated_at
```

So I build that function.
The purpose is to insert or update the row into the matching partition (partition for year)
and create the partition if it doesn't exists.

The insert works perfect, but the update just not working...

I get error that the new value is not match to the old partition..

EDIT:

I found this in the net:

> The schemes shown here assume that the partition key column(s) of a
>   row never change, or at least do not change enough to require it to
>   move to another partition. An UPDATE that attempts to do that will
>   fail because of the CHECK constraints. If you need to handle such
>   cases, you can put suitable update triggers on the partition tables,
>   but it makes management of the structure much more complicated.

I can understand that when you update the partition key, it's more complicated because it's include moving of row from one partition to another.

I just think that with simple delete from old partition and insert into new partition need to solve it..

What is the right way to do that?

```
--The error:
SQL Error [23514]: ERROR: new row for relation "items_prt_y2018" violates check constraint "items_prt_y2018_updated_at_check"
  Detail: Failing row contains (99887766, null, null, null, 2019-05-07 15:33:44.431274, null, null, 0, null, 0, null, 0, null, null, null, null, f, null, null, null, null, 0, 0, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, f, null, null, null, null, null).
  SQL Error [23514]: ERROR: new row for relation "items_prt_y2018" violates check constraint "items_prt_y2018_updated_at_check"
  Detail: Failing row contains (99887766, null, null, null, 2019-05-07 15:33:44.431274, null, null, 0, null, 0, null, 0, null, null, null, null, f, null, null, null, null, 0, 0, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, f, null, null, null, null, null).
    SQL Error [23514]: ERROR: new row for relation "items_prt_y2018" violates check constraint "items_prt_y2018_updated_at_check"
  Detail: Failing row contains (99887766, null, null, null, 2019-05-07 15:33:44.431274, null, null, 0, null, 0, null, 0, null, null, null, null, f, null, null, null, null, 0, 0, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, f, null, null, null, null, null).
      SQL Error [23514]: ERROR: new row for relation "items_prt_y2018" violates check constraint "items_prt_y2018_updated_at_check"
  Detail: Failing row contains (99887766, null, null, null, 2019-05-07 15:33:44.431274, null, null, 0, null, 0, null, 0, null, null, null, null, f, null, null, null, null, 0, 0, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, f, null, null, null, null, null).
        ERROR: new row for relation "items_prt_y2018" violates check constraint "items_prt_y2018_updated_at_check"
  Detail: Failing row contains (99887766, null, null, null, 2019-05-07 15:33:44.431274, null, null, 0, null, 0, null, 0, null, null, null, null, f, null, null, null, null, 0, 0, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, f, null, null, null, null, null).
        ERROR: new row for relation "items_prt_y2018" violates check constraint "items_prt_y2018_updated_at_check"
  Detail: Failing row contains (99887766, null, null, null, 2019-05-07 15:33:44.431274, null, null, 0, null, 0, null, 0, null, null, null, null, f, null, null, null, null, 0, 0, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, f, null, null, null, null, null).

-- The constraint of partition:
CREATE TABLE public.items_prt_y2018 (
    CONSTRAINT items_prt_y2018_updated_at_check CHECK (((updated_at >= '2018-01-01'::date) AND (updated_at < '2019-01-01'::date)))
)
INHERITS (public.items_prt)
WITH (
    OIDS=FALSE
) ;

-- table DDL
CREATE TABLE public.items_prt (
    id serial NOT NULL,
    "desc" text NULL,
    user_id int4 NULL,
    created_at timestamp NULL,
    updated_at timestamp NULL,
    workflow_state varchar(255) NULL,
    transaction_type int4 NULL,
    priority int4 NULL DEFAULT 0,
    state_changed_at timestamp NULL,
    item_status int4 NULL DEFAULT 0,
    item_type_id int4 NULL,
    reject_reason int4 NULL DEFAULT 0,
    public_id varchar(255) NULL,
    headline varchar(255) NULL,
    buyers_invoice_sent bool NULL,
    initial_transaction_type int4 NULL,
    high_value_diamond bool NULL DEFAULT false,
    user_estimation text NULL,
    last_reimbursement_date date NULL,
    bogus bool NULL,
    bundle_id int4 NULL,
    value_category int4 NULL DEFAULT 0,
    shipment_cost float8 NULL DEFAULT 0,
    grading_by_company_id int4 NULL,
    arrived_at timestamp NULL,
    reserve_price float8 NULL,
    trade_in bool NULL,
    competition int4 NULL,
    current_item_location_name varchar(255) NULL,
    current_location_id int4 NULL,
    submitted_from varchar(255) NULL,
    store_id int4 NULL,
    was_reserve_price_changed bool NULL DEFAULT false,
    future_lead_id int4 NULL,
    referrer_id int4 NULL,
    approve_unmount_stone bool NULL,
    full_reserve_price float8 NULL,
    negotiation_minimum_price float8 NULL,
    CONSTRAINT items_prt_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITH (
    OIDS=FALSE
) ;


-- function for the trigger
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.sf_items_prt_insert_update()
 RETURNS trigger
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$

    -- get the new year and the next year into variables
    declare v_year varchar(100) :=extract (year from new.updated_at);
    declare v_next_year varchar(100) :=extract (year from new.updated_at + interval '1 year');

BEGIN

    -- create new partition for the entered year if it doesn't exists yet
    execute
    'CREATE TABLE if not exists items_prt_y' || v_year || '(
    CHECK ( updated_at >= DATE ''' || v_year || '-01-01'' AND updated_at < DATE ''' || v_next_year || '-01-01'' )
) INHERITS (items_prt);';

    -- insert the new row if this is a new row
    if (TG_OP = 'INSERT') then
        -- insert the new row into the new partition
        execute 'insert into items_prt_y' || v_year || ' select ($1).*' using new;
    end;

    if (TG_OP = 'UPDATE') then
        if extract (year from new.updated_at) <> extract (year from old.updated_at) then

            execute immediate 'delete from items_prt where id = ' || old.id;

            -- insert the new row into the new partition
            execute 'insert into items_prt_y' || v_year || ' select ($1).*' using new;
    end;

    -- return null because we don't want the row will insert\update again after the trigger ends
    RETURN NULL;

END;
$function$;

-- trigger
CREATE TRIGGER trg_items_prt_insert_update
    before insert or update ON items_prt
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE sf_items_prt_insert_update();

-- working insert
insert into items_prt (id, updated_at) values (99887766, now());

-- not working update
update items_prt set updated_at = now() 
+ interval '1 year' 
where id = 99887766;
```

Comment: "Not working" and a vague error description is not enough. Provide the exact error message, and ideally SQL so that people can reproduce the problem.

Comment: I added the information

Comment: Is this trigger code your REAL code? There should be "end if" not "end" at the if code block end. Also you miss one "end if". After editing this all executes smooth, even the update.

Comment: Even with those fixes i got this error..  It is realy strange,  if function return null so it isnt need to do anything after..  Isn't it?  The error looks like it try to update anyway.